# tensor operation in tf2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I would like to get an output by applying a function on a tensor in the model. I tried both tensor operators and numpy functions but both failed. The operation I would apply is

```
def output2_new_from_output1_result(output1):
  start_new = np.zeros((1, output1.shape[1]))

  for step in range(output1.shape[1]):
      cans = np.where(output1[:, step] != 0)[0]
      if len(cans) > 0:
          for i in cans:
              if output1[i, step] == 1 and output1[i, step-1] == 0:
                  start_new[:, step] = 1
```

output1 is an output in the model, and I would like to get another output from that output1.

A colab notebook about this is [colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Om-uorkp4UqaJ2l2XgQLB_yMBKMthRC4)

Comment: you could convert the tensor to numpy array: `output1.numpy()`

Comment: I have tried that but get error: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'